# Disabled Input Button CSS Rules Not Working In Mobile Safari

Tags: css, css-selectors, mobile-safari

I am trying to style disabled buttons using the CSS :disabled pseudo-selector. For some reason, the "border-radius" rule is not respected using iOS Mobile Safari. I wrote a simple HTML page to demonstrate the problem (bug?). The following example works in Firefox, Chrome, and IE/Edge, but not on an iPhone/iPod Touch. You can test the example by copy/pasting the HTML code into https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_intro

Scroll down to see screenshots of the example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>iOS Safari CSS But Demonstration</title>
<style>
input[type="button"],
input[type="submit"],
button,
input[type="button"]:disabled,
input[type="submit"]:disabled,
button:disabled {
    min-width:300px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color: #000000;
    font-size: inherit;
    padding: 2px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 1;

    /*
    neither of the following border-radius rules
    seem to work in iOS Safari
    */
    border-radius: 0px !important;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px !important;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
Disabled Input Example--the following disabled input<br/>
is supposed to have square corners (border-radius: 0px) but<br/>
instead they are rounded when viewed in an iOS Safari browser:<br/>
<input type="button" value="I should have square corners." disabled/>
</body>
</html>
```

### iOS Screenshot:

[image]

### Firefox Screenshot:

[image]

### Why are the "border-radius" CSS rules for disabled elements not respected in iOS Mobile Safari?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out: by default, iOS Mobile Safari will override some CSS rules (including border-radius). To disable this behavior, set the following rule:

```
-webkit-appearance:none;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/appearance

Comment: this is not working any more